# Achieving More FMA3 Performance Than The Theoretical Maximum

Tags: c, benchmarking, avx2, flops, fma

For an assignment, I am trying to calculate the theoretical maximum achievable GFLOPS/sec of a single core of my processor, an AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS. According to Agner Fog's tables for a Zen 3 AMD processor (since the R9 5900HS is a Zen 3 processor), the reciprocal throughput of an `vfmadd132pd` operation is 0.5, giving us a maximum of 2 FMA3 operations per clock. Since each AVX2 vector can hold 4 doubles, that gives us a theoretical maximum of 8 FLOPS/clock. Since my cores average frequency is 3.16 clocks/sec, we get an average theoretical maximum of 25 GFLOPS/sec. All good so far.

Now, the issue arises when I run the [Flops benchmark](https://github.com/Mysticial/Flops/tree/master). Running the recommended 2017-Zen binary (both using the precompiled binary present in the repo, and compiling locally), gives me the results

```
Running Zen tuned binary with 1 thread...

Single-Precision - 128-bit AVX - Add/Sub
    GFlops = 22.528
    Result = 2.86329e+06

Double-Precision - 128-bit AVX - Add/Sub
    GFlops = 11.296
    Result = 1.43905e+06

Single-Precision - 128-bit AVX - Multiply
    GFlops = 25.536
    Result = 3.26002e+06

Double-Precision - 128-bit AVX - Multiply
    GFlops = 12.768
    Result = 1.63224e+06

Single-Precision - 128-bit AVX - Multiply + Add
    GFlops = 33.936
    Result = 3.62228e+06

Double-Precision - 128-bit AVX - Multiply + Add
    GFlops = 16.992
    Result = 1.80521e+06

Single-Precision - 128-bit FMA3 - Fused Multiply Add
    GFlops = 48.48
    Result = 3.09552e+06

Double-Precision - 128-bit FMA3 - Fused Multiply Add
    GFlops = 24.24
    Result = 1.53887e+06

Single-Precision - 256-bit AVX - Add/Sub
    GFlops = 45.12
    Result = 5.74426e+06

Double-Precision - 256-bit AVX - Add/Sub
    GFlops = 22.592
    Result = 2.88426e+06

Single-Precision - 256-bit AVX - Multiply
    GFlops = 50.976
    Result = 6.46382e+06

Double-Precision - 256-bit AVX - Multiply
    GFlops = 25.488
    Result = 3.2681e+06

Single-Precision - 256-bit AVX - Multiply + Add
    GFlops = 67.872
    Result = 7.20537e+06

Double-Precision - 256-bit AVX - Multiply + Add
    GFlops = 32.88
    Result = 3.48666e+06

Single-Precision - 256-bit FMA3 - Fused Multiply Add
    GFlops = 96.768
    Result = 6.14762e+06

Double-Precision - 256-bit FMA3 - Fused Multiply Add
    GFlops = 48.48
    Result = 3.07488e+06
```

As you can see, the GFlops calculated in the Double Precision 256 bit FMA3 benchmark is 48.48, almost double the theoretical maximum I calculated for my core. (Note that I monitored the CPU frequency in Task manager, and it was fixed at 3.16, occasionally going to 3.17, throughout the benchmark) I considered that the benchmark may  be wrong, so I inspected the binary of the 2017-Zen executable, and I found the following assembly for the Double Precision 256 bit FMA3 benchmark,

```
0000000000005130 <Flops::f64v2_FMA_FMA3_c12x4::run_kernel(unsigned long) const>:
    5130:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    5134:       c5 d0 57 ed             vxorps xmm5,xmm5,xmm5
    5138:       48 89 f1                mov    rcx,rsi
    513b:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    513d:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    5140:       c4 e1 d3 2a d0          vcvtsi2sd xmm2,xmm5,rax
    5145:       c4 e2 7d 19 d2          vbroadcastsd ymm2,xmm2
    514a:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    514c:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    514f:       c4 e1 d3 2a e0          vcvtsi2sd xmm4,xmm5,rax
    5154:       c4 e2 7d 19 e4          vbroadcastsd ymm4,xmm4
    5159:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    515b:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    515e:       c4 e1 d3 2a d8          vcvtsi2sd xmm3,xmm5,rax
    5163:       c4 e2 7d 19 db          vbroadcastsd ymm3,xmm3
    5168:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    516a:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    516d:       c4 61 d3 2a c0          vcvtsi2sd xmm8,xmm5,rax
    5172:       c4 42 7d 19 c0          vbroadcastsd ymm8,xmm8
    5177:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    5179:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    517c:       c4 e1 d3 2a f8          vcvtsi2sd xmm7,xmm5,rax
    5181:       c4 e2 7d 19 ff          vbroadcastsd ymm7,xmm7
    5186:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    5188:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    518b:       c4 e1 d3 2a f0          vcvtsi2sd xmm6,xmm5,rax
    5190:       c4 e2 7d 19 f6          vbroadcastsd ymm6,xmm6
    5195:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    5197:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    519a:       c4 61 d3 2a e8          vcvtsi2sd xmm13,xmm5,rax
    519f:       c4 42 7d 19 ed          vbroadcastsd ymm13,xmm13
    51a4:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    51a6:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    51a9:       c4 61 d3 2a d8          vcvtsi2sd xmm11,xmm5,rax
    51ae:       c4 42 7d 19 db          vbroadcastsd ymm11,xmm11
    51b3:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    51b5:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    51b8:       c4 61 d3 2a c8          vcvtsi2sd xmm9,xmm5,rax
    51bd:       c4 42 7d 19 c9          vbroadcastsd ymm9,xmm9
    51c2:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    51c4:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    51c7:       c4 61 d3 2a e0          vcvtsi2sd xmm12,xmm5,rax
    51cc:       c4 42 7d 19 e4          vbroadcastsd ymm12,xmm12
    51d1:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    51d3:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    51d6:       c4 61 d3 2a d0          vcvtsi2sd xmm10,xmm5,rax
    51db:       c4 42 7d 19 d2          vbroadcastsd ymm10,xmm10
    51e0:       0f 31                   rdtsc
    51e2:       c5 fd 28 0d 76 15 00 00         vmovapd ymm1,YMMWORD PTR [rip+0x1576]        # 6760 <typeinfo name for Flops::f64v2_FMA_FMA3_c12x4+0xb0>
    51ea:       c5 fd 28 05 2e 16 00 00         vmovapd ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rip+0x162e]        # 6820 <typeinfo name for Flops::f64v2_FMA_FMA3_c12x4+0x170>
    51f2:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
    51f5:       c4 e1 d3 2a e8          vcvtsi2sd xmm5,xmm5,rax
    51fa:       c4 e2 7d 19 ed          vbroadcastsd ymm5,xmm5
    51ff:       90                      nop
    5200:       c4 e2 f5 b8 d0          vfmadd231pd ymm2,ymm1,ymm0
    5205:       c4 e2 f5 b8 e0          vfmadd231pd ymm4,ymm1,ymm0
    520a:       48 ff c9                dec    rcx
    520d:       c4 e2 f5 b8 d8          vfmadd231pd ymm3,ymm1,ymm0
    5212:       c4 62 f5 b8 c0          vfmadd231pd ymm8,ymm1,ymm0
    5217:       c4 e2 f5 b8 f8          vfmadd231pd ymm7,ymm1,ymm0
    521c:       c4 e2 f5 b8 f0          vfmadd231pd ymm6,ymm1,ymm0
    5221:       c4 62 f5 b8 e8          vfmadd231pd ymm13,ymm1,ymm0
    5226:       c4 62 f5 b8 d8          vfmadd231pd ymm11,ymm1,ymm0
    522b:       c4 62 f5 b8 c8          vfmadd231pd ymm9,ymm1,ymm0
    5230:       c4 62 f5 b8 e0          vfmadd231pd ymm12,ymm1,ymm0
    5235:       c4 62 f5 b8 d0          vfmadd231pd ymm10,ymm1,ymm0
    523a:       c4 e2 f5 b8 e8          vfmadd231pd ymm5,ymm1,ymm0
    523f:       c4 e2 f5 bc d0          vfnmadd231pd ymm2,ymm1,ymm0
    5244:       c4 e2 f5 bc e0          vfnmadd231pd ymm4,ymm1,ymm0
    5249:       c4 e2 f5 bc d8          vfnmadd231pd ymm3,ymm1,ymm0
    524e:       c4 62 f5 bc c0          vfnmadd231pd ymm8,ymm1,ymm0
    5253:       c4 e2 f5 bc f8          vfnmadd231pd ymm7,ymm1,ymm0
    5258:       c4 e2 f5 bc f0          vfnmadd231pd ymm6,ymm1,ymm0
    525d:       c4 62 f5 bc e8          vfnmadd231pd ymm13,ymm1,ymm0
    5262:       c4 62 f5 bc d8          vfnmadd231pd ymm11,ymm1,ymm0
    5267:       c4 62 f5 bc c8          vfnmadd231pd ymm9,ymm1,ymm0
    526c:       c4 62 f5 bc e0          vfnmadd231pd ymm12,ymm1,ymm0
    5271:       c4 62 f5 bc d0          vfnmadd231pd ymm10,ymm1,ymm0
    5276:       c4 e2 f5 bc e8          vfnmadd231pd ymm5,ymm1,ymm0
    527b:       c4 e2 f5 b8 d0          vfmadd231pd ymm2,ymm1,ymm0
    5280:       c4 e2 f5 b8 e0          vfmadd231pd ymm4,ymm1,ymm0
    5285:       c4 e2 f5 b8 d8          vfmadd231pd ymm3,ymm1,ymm0
    528a:       c4 62 f5 b8 c0          vfmadd231pd ymm8,ymm1,ymm0
    528f:       c4 e2 f5 b8 f8          vfmadd231pd ymm7,ymm1,ymm0
    5294:       c4 e2 f5 b8 f0          vfmadd231pd ymm6,ymm1,ymm0
    5299:       c4 62 f5 b8 e8          vfmadd231pd ymm13,ymm1,ymm0
    529e:       c4 62 f5 b8 d8          vfmadd231pd ymm11,ymm1,ymm0
    52a3:       c4 62 f5 b8 c8          vfmadd231pd ymm9,ymm1,ymm0
    52a8:       c4 62 f5 b8 e0          vfmadd231pd ymm12,ymm1,ymm0
    52ad:       c4 62 f5 b8 d0          vfmadd231pd ymm10,ymm1,ymm0
    52b2:       c4 e2 f5 b8 e8          vfmadd231pd ymm5,ymm1,ymm0
    52b7:       c4 e2 f5 bc d0          vfnmadd231pd ymm2,ymm1,ymm0
    52bc:       c4 e2 f5 bc e0          vfnmadd231pd ymm4,ymm1,ymm0
    52c1:       c4 e2 f5 bc d8          vfnmadd231pd ymm3,ymm1,ymm0
    52c6:       c4 62 f5 bc c0          vfnmadd231pd ymm8,ymm1,ymm0
    52cb:       c4 e2 f5 bc f8          vfnmadd231pd ymm7,ymm1,ymm0
    52d0:       c4 e2 f5 bc f0          vfnmadd231pd ymm6,ymm1,ymm0
    52d5:       c4 62 f5 bc e8          vfnmadd231pd ymm13,ymm1,ymm0
    52da:       c4 62 f5 bc d8          vfnmadd231pd ymm11,ymm1,ymm0
    52df:       c4 62 f5 bc c8          vfnmadd231pd ymm9,ymm1,ymm0
    52e4:       c4 62 f5 bc e0          vfnmadd231pd ymm12,ymm1,ymm0
    52e9:       c4 62 f5 bc d0          vfnmadd231pd ymm10,ymm1,ymm0
    52ee:       c4 e2 f5 bc e8          vfnmadd231pd ymm5,ymm1,ymm0
    52f3:       0f 85 07 ff ff ff       jne    5200 <Flops::f64v2_FMA_FMA3_c12x4::run_kernel(unsigned long) const+0xd0>
    52f9:       c4 c1 6d 58 c5          vaddpd ymm0,ymm2,ymm13
    52fe:       c4 41 3d 58 c4          vaddpd ymm8,ymm8,ymm12
    5303:       c4 c1 5d 58 e3          vaddpd ymm4,ymm4,ymm11
    5308:       c4 c1 45 58 fa          vaddpd ymm7,ymm7,ymm10
    530d:       c4 c1 65 58 d9          vaddpd ymm3,ymm3,ymm9
    5312:       c5 cd 58 f5             vaddpd ymm6,ymm6,ymm5
    5316:       c4 c1 7d 58 c0          vaddpd ymm0,ymm0,ymm8
    531b:       c5 dd 58 e7             vaddpd ymm4,ymm4,ymm7
    531f:       c5 e5 58 de             vaddpd ymm3,ymm3,ymm6
    5323:       c5 fd 58 c4             vaddpd ymm0,ymm0,ymm4
    5327:       c5 fd 58 c3             vaddpd ymm0,ymm0,ymm3
    532b:       c4 e3 7d 19 c1 01       vextractf128 xmm1,ymm0,0x1
    5331:       c5 f1 58 c0             vaddpd xmm0,xmm1,xmm0
    5335:       c5 f9 15 c8             vunpckhpd xmm1,xmm0,xmm0
    5339:       c5 f9 58 c1             vaddpd xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
    533d:       c5 f8 77                vzeroupper
    5340:       c3                      ret
```

The number of FMA3 operations in the loop is indeed 48, giving us 48x2x4 operations per loop, which validates the code in the file f64v2_FMA_FMA3_c12x4.h in the repo. Clearly either I am wrong, or the benchmark is wrong, but I can't figure out who. If it matters, all code is being run in WSL2 on Windows 10.

Comment: One FMA counts as two FLOPs, doing as much work as a multiply and add.  Only some problems can contract most of their multiplies and adds into FMAs, but CPUs with FMA support can sometimes run such workloads almost twice as fast, if that doesn't just shift the bottleneck to something like loads and stores to L1d cache.

Comment: @PeterCordes that makes sense, I believe I got confused with my understanding of FLOPs, thank you for your help!